# Unit test using Jasmine returning TypeError: is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to do a unit test using Jasmine and calling my Angular 5 services, but I got the following error

`TypeError: this.dailySalesService.resetValues is not a function`

This occurs when the method `changeDate` in `component.changeDate(new Date());` is called. Inside the `changeDate` method I call the `dailySalesService` correctly, so I think isn't a error in my component.

**My Unit Test**

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LayoutService } from './../../core/services/layout.service';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HomeDailySalesComponent } from './home-daily-sales.component';
import { HomeDailySalesProgressComponent } from './home-daily-sales-progress.component';
import { DailySalesService } from '../shared/daily-sales.service';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('Component: HomeDailySalesComponent', () => {
    let component: HomeDailySalesComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeDailySalesComponent>;
    const dailySalesServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('DailySalesService', ['getSummarySalesDay']);

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                TextMaskModule,
                FormsModule
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: DailySalesService, useValue: dailySalesServiceMock }
            ],
            declarations: [
                HomeDailySalesComponent,
                HomeDailySalesProgressComponent
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeDailySalesComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should return service success without content', () => {
        dailySalesServiceMock.getSummarySalesDay.and.callFake(function () {
            return Observable.of({});
        });

        // error here, when changeDate is called
        component.changeDate(new Date());
        expect(component.error).toBeTruthy();
        expect(dailySalesServiceMock.getSummarySalesDay).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
});
```

**The Log error**

```
at <Jasmine>
    at HomeDailySalesComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/home/home-daily-sales/home-daily-sales.component.ts.HomeDailySalesComponent.changeDate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/home/home-daily-sales/home-daily-sales.component.ts:53:56)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/home/home-daily-sales/home-daily-sales.component.spec.ts:105:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:145:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:160:1)
    at <Jasmine>
```

Comment: Does it help of you add `resetValues` to the list of mocked functions of the `DailySalesService` spy object? Just a guess on my part.

Comment: @R.Richards sorry for that. Is exactly this.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos, were you able to fix this issue?